# Parsing response.getEntity(String.class) string to xml with DocumentHelper.parseText() in dom4j

Tags: xml-parsing, dom4j

dom4j has no trouble doing

```
String text = "<person> <name>James</name> </person>";
Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);
```

What I need is this

```
String text = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"+
"<person> <name>James</name> </person>";
Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);
```

But it throws an exception.

```
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : parsing initialization error: org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed outside root element at line 1 and column 1 seen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem. The before line below is the one that fails. The after line works.

BEFORE

```
Document output = DocumentHelper.parseText(response.getEntity(String.class));
```

AFTER

```
Document output = DocumentHelper.parseText(response.getEntity(String.class).trim());
```